# Java abstract class implements interface

Tags: java, class, interface, abstract

I have the following interface and abstract class that implements it:

```
interface Walk {
    String walk();
}

public abstract class Animal implements Walk {
    abstract String MakeNoise();
}
```

And the following concrete implementations:

```
class Cat extends Animal {
    String MakeNoise() {
        return "Meow";
    }

    @Override
    String walk() {
        return "cat is walking";
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    @Override
    String walk() {
        return "Dog is walking";
    }

    @Override
    String MakeNoise() {
        return "bark";
    }
}

class Human {
    public void Speak() {
        System.out.println("...Speaking...");
    }
}
```

Putting it all together:

```
class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random randomGen = new Random();

        Animal[] zoo = new Animal[4];
        zoo[0] = new Cat();
        zoo[1] = new Dog();
        zoo[2] = new Cat();
        zoo[3] = new Cat();
        // System.out.println(zoo[ randomGen.nextInt(2)].MakeNoise());
        for (Animal animal : zoo) {
            if (animal instanceof Dog) {
                Dog jeffrey = (Dog) animal;
                System.out.println(jeffrey.MakeNoise());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I get this error

> "walk() in Cat cannot implement walk() in Walk " .

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: That's not what the error says.

Comment: a question of my own.... should Animal provide an "implementation" (even if it is an abstract method) of walk()?

Comment: I still doubt that's what the error says.  If you want effective help, give effective information: copy the error message *verbatim* into your question.

Comment: @SJuan: How does `Animal` redeclaring `walk()` as an abstract method make it provide an "implementation"?  It would have absolutely no effect, other than on style.  Or rather, if you were wondering if it *needs* to do so, the answer is no it doesn't, as long as `Animal` is declared `abstract`.

Comment: @MarkPeters yes I know, I am just asking about the style part. It would just seem more regular if every class that "implements" an interface had to declare the interface methods, even if the class itself (and the method) was abstract.

Comment: @SJuan: You could argue a couple of points either way, but not redeclaring it makes it easier to change the interface.  If you don't use the `@Override` annotation it's a little more dangerous to redeclare the methods.  The only gain I can think of for redeclaring them is so you can see upfront what needs to be implemented, but that's what IDEs are for IMO.

Comment: When typing in error messages, the only keys your fingers should be touching are `ctl/command-c` and `ctl/command-v`.

Comment: @lwburk Thanks for the tip (Jcreator)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Methods in interfaces are implicitly `public`.  However, methods in classes are package-visible by default.  You cannot reduce the visibility of an overriden method, i.e. you can't do stuff like this:

```
class A {
    public foo() {}
}

class B extends A {
    private foo() {}  // No!
}

class C extends A {
    foo() {}          // No! foo is package-visible, which is lower than public
}
```

In your case, the solution is to declare `walk()` as `public` in `Dog` and `Cat`.

Comment: What surprises me is that interface was declared as package not public. Thanks

Comment: That was a nice catch, Oli. I tell ya, the worst of the bugs I've had to deal with have always come down to silly stuff like this.

Answer (score 2):

The error eclipse gives is:

> Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from Walk

The method must be public, because it is defined in an interface.

Answer (score 1):

Interface methods must be public. You need to declare `walk()` as a public method in Cat.

Answer (score 1):

Make `String walk()` implementations `public`. That will fix it